# Figuring out which functions are Big-O of other functions (of a of 9 different functions). Where do I start?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

**Problem**

I need to arrange the following functions in order, so that each function is big-oh of the next function.

**Functions**

[image: List of functions (not ordered)]

**Attempt @ Solution**

1. Understanding: I don't understand what to do here.  My best guess is to determine what each function is Big-Oh of, and then rank the functions in order of magnitude of Big-Oh.  Is that a way to start?

Comment: Rank the functions in increasing order, where you think of $n$ as huge. The last item in the list is the big loser, so first in the list, since for big $n$ it is roughly equal to $1$, while the others go to infinity, some kind of slowly. Now remember log is slow, a little power of $n$ beats log, but is beaten by a bigger power of $n$. Exponentials are real fast. Factorials are real fast too. This is an important exercise, since for algorithm analysis purposes you need good intuition about which functions grow faster than which. (I have left out mention of some in the list.)

Comment: You are welcome. Two of the items, $2^n$ and $\sum_0^n 2^i$, end up tied in the race, each is big $O$ of the other. The other one you might have a little trouble with is $\sum_1^n \log_2 i$. Half the terms are $\ge \log_2(n/2)$, so it grows basically like $n\log_2 n$.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is essentially to rank the nine functions in order of increasing growth rates. You know, for instance, that $2^n$ grows faster than $n^2$, and hence that $n^2$ is $O(2^n)$; thus, $n^2$ will come somewhere before $2^n$ in your ranking.

The first five are already fairly basic functions: you should definitely know the proper order for $n!$, $2^n$, $n^2$, $\sqrt n$, and you should probably know where $\log_2n$ fits into that list. The other four will require some work; in each case it would be helpful to find a simple function $g(n)$ such that the given function is $\Theta\big(g(n)\big)$, i.e., both $O\big(g(n)\big)$ **and** $\Omega\big(g(n)\big)$.

I’ll get you started on one of them and add some hints for the rest. From the formula for the sum of a geometric series you know that $$\sum_{i=0}^n2^i=\frac{2^{n+1}-2^0}{2-1}=2^{n+1}-1\;.$$ This suggests that you should try to show that $\sum_{i=0}^n2^i$ is $\Theta(2^{n+1})$, since for large $n$ that $-1$ is going to be insignificant.

You may have to dig it out, but there’s a known formula for the sum of the first $n$ perfect squares; you can use that to work out the growth rate of $\sum_{i=0}^ni^2$. Use the properties of logarithms to simplify $\sum_{i=1}^n\log_2i$; it’s the log base $2$ of what function of $n$? As for the last one, what limit does it approach as $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

For a starter, the last function is the slowest, because you can take (numerator is $a(n)$, denominator $d(n)$:

$$
\frac{a(n)}{d(n)}\leq \frac{(n+3)^3}{(n-3)^3} \leq \frac{3n^3}{\frac{n^3}{3}}=9=O(1)
$$

The rest of your functions are $\omega(1)$, i.e. the tend to infinity as $n \to \infty$